# ESRI Sample ArcGIS Server For Origin Destination Cost Matrix Service (REST)

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst

ESRI is providing sample of REST API for Origin Destination Cost Matrix service on their ArcGIS Online at here

[ArcGIS Online Directions and Routing Services](https://logistics.arcgis.com)

Can you please let me know if there is any ArcGIS Server (GP Server) for testing the Origin Destination Cost Matrix service from REST?

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial, but instead of choosing "new route" choose "new OD cost matrix"?  http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-publishing-a-network-analysis-service.htm

Answer (score 1):

The Origin Destination Cost Matrix is referenced in the [Esri dev labs](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/directions/#travel-cost) and you can find specific labs for [Network Analyst here](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/browse/?topic=Routing&product=any). However, there isn't a specific dev lab for OD-CM. Regardless, these are good links for learning.

The [OD-CM Rest API is documented](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/network/api-reference/origin-destination-cost-matrix-service.htm). From this link, it references the REST API URL for it:  https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/OriginDestinationCostMatrix/GPServer/GenerateOriginDestinationCostMatrix/submitJob?parameters

Using the API doc, the URL to GenerateOriginDestinationCostMatrix and some of the tips in the DevLabs, you should have enough information to start testing.

Comment: Thanks Khibma but the link you commented is ArcGIS Online and I need a an ArcGIS Server

Comment: The link I reference is a GP Service running on the cloud (Arcgis.com) -- what does one running on some other box offer that this one doesn't?

Comment: They are NA services for routing there but I couldn't find anything thing for Origin Destination Cost Matrix

Comment: The link I reference is ODCM. logistics.arcgis.com has the REST Service Directory browsing turned off, so you cant poke around it. I'm still not clear what you're looking for if the link I referenced isn't "it"